# Angular 7 : Looping through complex object and populating the table

Tags: angular

I am trying to pass object to an angular component. I need to loop through the object and populate the table. Currently I have passed two objects. I am able to get the length of the TrackRecord object as it is simple array. 
I cant seem to get the length of the FundStatistics object as it seems to be complex. I presume there is data in the object.

JSON structure of  FundStatistics

```
"{"237146":[{"m_Item1":"ArithmeticMean","m_Item2":0.005521221052631577,"m_Item3":0.01912607076595362},{"m_Item1":"AverageGain","m_Item2":0.038913171935483874,"m_Item3":0.13479918175184283},{"m_Item1":"AverageLoss","m_Item2":-0.03429225884615385,"m_Item3":-0.11879186925568348}]}"
```

Looping the component and passing the data

```
 <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading product-heading">
            <span style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;">Performance Track Record and Statistics</span>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf ="ViewModel.FundPerformance" class="panel-body" style="width:100%">
            <div *ngFor="let ftr of ViewModel.FundPerformance">
                <div style="clear: both;"></div>
                <br /><br />
                <fund-statistics [fundStatistics]="ftr.FundStatistics"  [fundTrackRecord]= "ftr.TrackRecord"></fund-statistics>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

The component code

```
export class FundStatisticsComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() fundStatistics: any;
    @Input() fundTrackRecord: any;

    ngOnInit() {
    }
}
```

Following is the table that I want to populate. I basically want to populate For e.g m_Item2 of ArithmeticMean of the array in first column under Arithmetic Mean in the table and m_Item3 of ArithmeticMean in the array  under second column of Arithmetic Mean in the table

```
<div *ngFor="let fundStats of fundStatistics">

    <table class="statsTable">
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td colspan="2" class="tableItem header">Fund Name</td>

                    <td colspan="2" class="headerTableItem header">Benchmark</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td class="tableItem bold">Monthly </td>
                    <td class="tableItem bold">Annualized</td>
                    <td class="tableItem bold">Monthly </td>
                    <td class="tableItem bold">Annualized</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="rowItem">
                    <td class="titleTableItem header">Compound ROR</td>
                    <td class="tableItem"></td>
                    <td class="tableItem"></td>
                    <td class="tableItem"></td>
                    <td class="tableItem"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="rowItem">
                    <td class="titleTableItem  header">Arithmetic Mean </td>
                    <td class="tableItem"></td>
                    <td class="tableItem"></td>
                    <td class="tableItem"></td>
                    <td class="tableItem"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="rowItem">
                    <td class="titleTableItem  header">Standard Deviation</td>
                    <td class="tableItem"></td>
                    <td class="tableItem"></td>
                    <td class="tableItem"></td>
                    <td class="tableItem"></td>
                </tr>

    </table>            
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*ngFor` doesn’t support iterations over objects or Maps.
You could either use `Object.keys(fundStatistics)` to get the keys, and then use those as values for `*ngFor`

```
export class FundStatisticsComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() fundStatistics: any;
    @Input() fundTrackRecord: any;
    fundStatisticksKeys = [];

    ngOnInit() {
        this.fundStatisticksKeys = Object.keys(this.fundStatistics);
    }
}
```

And then in your template do something like

```
<div *ngFor="let key of fundStatisticksKeys">
```

and get the current element as `fundStatistics[key]`

Starting from Angular 6.1 there is also a new Pipe called `KeyValuePipe` https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe#description which can be used exactly for cases like these

In this case you don't need to get the object keys beforehand, just use the pipe in your template and you will get `fundStats.key`and `fundStats.value` in your template, like `fundStats.value.m_Item1`

```
<div *ngFor="let fundStats of fundStatistics | keyvalue">
```

**Edit**
Then in order to populate the table you could use interpolation like this, if I understand correctly what you need. `value` will hold the value of the entry you're looping on

```
<tr class="rowItem">
    <td class="titleTableItem  header">Arithmetic Mean </td>
    <td class="tableItem">{{ fundStats.value.m_Item2 }}</td>
    <td class="tableItem">{{ fundStats.value.m_Item3 }}</td>
    <td class="tableItem"></td>
    <td class="tableItem"></td>
</tr>
```

If you have don't have a fixed number of m_Item* value, you could use a ngFor to loop on those as well

Comment: And how do you suggest I assign values to columns in the table as I mentioned in the post

Comment: Isn’t in my case key and multiple values

Comment: @Tom I've updated the answer. As far as I recall, .value will hold the value of the entry you're looping on

Comment: you could also make getters for those keys like `get keysOfMyObj()`  rather that defining them inside ngOninit or constructor