# Angular 7 : Looping through array and populating the table

Tags: angular

I am trying to populate a table in angular 7. The table will have fixed columns on the top which will be the first two rows and will have fixed label on the first column starting from the third row.

I need to loop through the array and populate the rest of the cells. At the moment it is printing three tables since i am having a outer loop. How do loop in way where only the cells are populated.

Currently this is how the data looks like

```json
[
  {
    "m_Item1": "ArithmeticMean",
    "m_Item2": 0.005521221052631577,
    "m_Item3": 0.01912607076595362
  },
  {
    "m_Item1": "AverageGain",
    "m_Item2": 0.038913171935483874,
    "m_Item3": 0.13479918175184283
  },
  {
    "m_Item1": "AverageLoss",
    "m_Item2": -0.03429225884615385,
    "m_Item3": -0.11879186925568348
  }
]
```

I need to populate the following table. Currently I have only set the Arithmetic mean, I need to assign all the other fields. But now my main concern is that how to only iterate the rows and not the table. Also please note that if rows are dynamic it needs to print empty cell if there is no data

[image]

Following is the code that i am using

```html
<div *ngFor="let fundStats of fundStatistics">
    <table class="statsTable">
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td colspan="2" class="tableItem header">Fund Name</td>

            <td colspan="2" class="headerTableItem header">Benchmark</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td class="tableItem bold">Monthly </td>
            <td class="tableItem bold">Annualized</td>
            <td class="tableItem bold">Monthly </td>
            <td class="tableItem bold">Annualized</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="rowItem">
            <td class="titleTableItem header">Compound ROR</td>
            <td class="tableItem"></td>
            <td class="tableItem"></td>
            <td class="tableItem"></td>
            <td class="tableItem"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="rowItem">
            <td class="titleTableItem  header">Arithmetic Mean </td>
            <td class="tableItem">{{fundStats.m_Item2}}</td>
            <td class="tableItem">{{fundStats.m_Item3}}</td>
            <td class="tableItem"></td>
            <td class="tableItem"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="rowItem">
            <td class="titleTableItem  header">Standard Deviation</td>
            <td class="tableItem"></td>
            <td class="tableItem"></td>
            <td class="tableItem"></td>
            <td class="tableItem"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="rowItem">
            <td class="titleTableItem  header">Average Gain</td>
            <td class="tableItem"></td>
            <td class="tableItem"></td>
            <td class="tableItem"></td>
            <td class="tableItem"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="rowItem">
            <td class="titleTableItem  header">Average Loss</td>
            <td class="tableItem"></td>
            <td class="tableItem"></td>
            <td class="tableItem"></td>
            <td class="tableItem"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="rowItem">
            <td class="titleTableItem  header">Downside Deviation</td>
            <td class="tableItem"></td>
            <td class="tableItem"></td>
            <td class="tableItem"></td>
            <td class="tableItem"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="rowItem">
            <td class="titleTableItem  header">Sharpe</td>
            <td class="tableItem"></td>
            <td class="tableItem"></td>
            <td class="tableItem"></td>
            <td class="tableItem"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="rowItem">
            <td class="titleTableItem  header">Sortino</td>
            <td class="tableItem"></td>
            <td class="tableItem"></td>
            <td class="tableItem"></td>
            <td class="tableItem"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="rowItem">
            <td class="titleTableItem  header">Skewness</td>
            <td class="tableItem"></td>
            <td class="tableItem"></td>
            <td class="tableItem"></td>
            <td class="tableItem"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="rowItem">
            <td class="titleTableItem  header">Kurtosis</td>
            <td class="tableItem"></td>
            <td class="tableItem"></td>
            <td class="tableItem"></td>
            <td class="tableItem"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="rowItem">
            <td class="titleTableItem header">Gain Deviation</td>
            <td class="tableItem"></td>
            <td class="tableItem"></td>
            <td class="tableItem"></td>
            <td class="tableItem"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="rowItem">
            <td class="titleTableItem header">Loss Deviation</td>
            <td class="tableItem"></td>
            <td class="tableItem"></td>
            <td class="tableItem"></td>
            <td class="tableItem"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="rowItem">
            <td class="titleTableItem  header" style="border-bottom: solid 1px lightgrey">Av Gain / Av Loss</td>
            <td class="tableItem" style="border-bottom: solid 1px lightgrey"></td>
            <td class="tableItem" style="border-bottom: solid 1px lightgrey"></td>
            <td class="tableItem" style="border-bottom: solid 1px lightgrey"></td>
            <td class="tableItem" style="border-bottom: solid 1px lightgrey"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 7 : Looping through complex object and populating the table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55581241/angular-7-looping-through-complex-object-and-populating-the-table)

Answer (score 0):

Keep your loop inside table to generate the rows

```
<table class="statsTable">
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td colspan="2" class="tableItem header">Fund Name</td>

            <td colspan="2" class="headerTableItem header">Benchmark</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td class="tableItem bold">Monthly </td>
            <td class="tableItem bold">Annualized</td>
            <td class="tableItem bold">Monthly </td>
            <td class="tableItem bold">Annualized</td>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngFor="let fundStats of fundStatistics">
          <td class="titleTableItem  header">{{fundStats.m_Item1}}</td>
            <td class="tableItem">{{fundStats.m_Item2}}</td>
            <td class="tableItem">{{fundStats.m_Item3}}</td>
            <td class="tableItem"></td>
            <td class="tableItem"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="rowItem">
            <td class="titleTableItem  header" style="border-bottom: solid 1px lightgrey">Av Gain / Av Loss</td>
            <td class="tableItem" style="border-bottom: solid 1px lightgrey"></td>
            <td class="tableItem" style="border-bottom: solid 1px lightgrey"></td>
            <td class="tableItem" style="border-bottom: solid 1px lightgrey"></td>
            <td class="tableItem" style="border-bottom: solid 1px lightgrey"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Check this out https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nlswav